# PHP Problems with constructing classes (variables and namespaces)

Tags: php, constructor, namespaces

I just got stuck with the following problem. I'm trying to construct a class but it isn't working. When I'm constructing the class it uses namespaces and variables, because the variable has to be put behind a backslash (for the namespace) it gives an error.
Here's an example code of defining the class;

```
$className = 'Help';
$controller = new \controller\$className;
```

The class name is defined in a variable, in the example code above I've just set it to 'Help'. When constructing the class it has `\controller\` in front of it, that's cause it's in that namespace. If I remove the namespace thing away so it just has;

```
$controller = new $className;
```

it does work. The problem is probably caused because there's a backslash in front of the variable which contains the class name to construct. I am not able to add `use controller;` in the beginning of the code because the file containing the class is loaded inside the constructor, and the class is immediately constructed after the file has been loaded. The `use` function could only be used in the beginning of your file, not inside a method, I think.

I hope someone could help me out,.

Thanks in advance,
Tim Visée

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example is invalid syntax.  You would need instead something like:

```
$className = '\controller\Help';
$controller = new $className();
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the fully qualified class name to a variable and use that to instantiate a new object:

```
$className = '\controller\Help';
$controller = new $className;
```